# Square a number with functions in python

Tags: python

This is an extremely easy question for Python.  It's very basic Python as I'm still a beginner...  to take a number, use a function and square it:

```
import math
nmb = int(raw_input("Enter a number to be squared: "))
def square(nmb):
    y = math.pow(nmb,2)
    return y
print str(nmb) + " squared is equal to " + str(square)
```

I've jiggered it around a few times, but the end result always prints something like "5 squared is equal to function square at 0x02BC87B0" instead of the result

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious, as my understanding of functions is still quite basic, but any pointers would set me on my way!

Comment: `import math` is overkill. Why not just `return nmb**2`?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the function `square`, not the return value of a call to `square`, to `str`. You want this:

```
print str(nmb) + " squared is equal to " + str(square(nmb))
```

Answer (score -3):

Write a python3 function `sqrt(n)` that returns the square of its numeric parameter `n`.

```py
import math
num = int(raw_input("Enter a number to be squared: "))
def square(num):
    y = math.pow(num,2)
    return y
print str(num) + " squared is equal to " + str(square(num))
```

Comment: I doubt that you should answer a beginner question 6 years ago without major improvements than another answer.

Comment: This answer is severely confused: It talks about python3, while the question (and the answer!) use python2. (old `print` syntax, `raw_input`). Also, why are you talking about `sqrt`, when the question is about `square`? Apart from that, this question is a bad copy of @chepner's answer with the explanation missing.